# Прослушивание PDF

Tags: linux, pdf

Поставил сегодня "лучшую программу синтеза речи Festival, разрабатываемую в Центре изучения речевых технологий в Эдинбургском университете (Шотландия). Она поддерживает множество различных языков и голосов, может читать текст из файла либо из командной строки и записывать результат синтеза в звуковой файл формата wav, включает в себя плагин для pidgin, проговаривающий входящие сообщения":

```
$sudo apt-get install festvox-ru
```

И теперь мой кранч стал хорошо говорящим по русски:

```
$ echo "Привет" | festival --language russian --tts
```

И можно прослушать книжку в текстовом формате:

```
$ festival --language russian --tts path/to/file.txt
```

У меня вопрос к тем, кто уже не первый день знаком с этой программой, можно ли заставить читать ее pdf? (Если да, то как?)

Answer (score 4):

Думается, самый простой выход - это преобразовать pdf в txt, а затем прослушивать этот txt. В Linux это делается так

```
pdftotext from to
```